# How to retrieve a single value from CosmosDB using c#

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How to retrieve a value from CosmosDB using c# linq?

I am using the following to retrieve value of date from COSMOS DB,but this says .first is not supported. Please help

container.GetItemLinqQueryable(true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it synchronous, you just need to call ToList() before First(), for example:

```
container.GetItemLinqQueryable(true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList().First();
```

But as you've mentioned, you have converted it to an async call using a FeedIterator which is the recommended way to do it. Here is a code sample based on your comment:

```
using var setIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Book>()
  .Where(b => b.Title == "War and Peace")
  .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
  .ToFeedIterator();

var books = new List<Book>();
while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)    
  foreach (var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())       
     books.Add(item);
```

Answer (score -2):

iterate with foreach and break after the first object.

Comment: Resolved

I used the below to resolve the issue

using (FeedIterator<Book> setIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Book>()
                      .Where(b => b.Title == "War and Peace")
                      .ToFeedIterator<Book>())
 {
     //Asynchronous query execution
     while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
     {
         foreach(var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync()){
         {
             Console.WriteLine(item.cost);
         }
       }
     }
 }

Comment: @Dev - this belongs as an answer, not as a comment (also it's *very* difficult to read code-in-comments)